# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress controller Readiness Probe failed

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, coredns

I am trying to setup my very first Kubernetes cluster and it seems to have setup fine until nginx-ingress controller.
Here is my cluster information:
Nodes: three RHEL7 and one RHEL8 nodes
Master is running on RHEL7
Kubernetes server version: 1.19.1
Networking used: flannel
coredns is running fine.
selinux and firewall are disabled on all nodes

Here are my all pods running in kube-system
[image: pods running in kube-system]

I then followed instructions on following page to install nginx ingress controller: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

Instead of deployment, I decided to use daemon-set since I am going to have only few nodes running in my kubernetes cluster.

After following the instructions, pod on my RHEL8 is constantly failing with the following error:

> Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.244.3.2:8081/nginx-ready": dial
> tcp 10.244.3.2:8081: connect: connection refused Back-off restarting
> failed container

Here is the screenshot shows that RHEL7 pods are working just fine and RHEL8 is failing:
[image: running and failing pods]

All nodes are setup exactly the same way and there is no difference.
I am very new to Kubernetes and don't know much internals of it. Can someone please point me on how can I debug and fix this issue? I am really willing to learn from issues like this.

**This is how I provisioned RHEL7 and RHEL8 nodes**

1. Installed docker version: 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
2. Disabled firewalld
3. Disabled swap
4. Disabled SELinux
5. To enable iptables to see bridged traffic, set net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1 and net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
6. Added hosts entry for all the nodes involved in Kubernetes cluster so that they can find each other without hitting DNS
7. Added IP address of all nodes in Kubernetes cluster on /etc/environment for no_proxy so that it doesn't hit corporate proxy
8. Verified docker driver to be "systemd" and NOT "cgroupfs"
9. Reboot server
10. Install kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet as per kubernetes guide here at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/
11. Start and enable kubelet service
12. Initialize master by executing the following:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.96.0.0/12
```

13. Apply node-selector patch for mixed OS scheduling

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/SDN/master/Kubernetes/flannel/l2bridge/manifests/node-selector-patch.yml
kubectl patch ds/kube-proxy --patch "$(cat node-selector-patch.yml)" -n=kube-system
```

14. Apply flannel CNI

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Modify net-conf.json section of kube-flannel.yml for a type "host-gw"

```
kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml
```

Apply node selector patch

```
kubectl patch ds/kube-flannel-ds-amd64 --patch "$(cat node-selector-patch.yml)" -n=kube-system
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you check that there's not DNS caching on the RHEL 8 node, e.g. dnsmasq.  If it was dnsmasq, you would see something like:
    cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns.conf 

    [main]
    dns=dnsmasq

Comment: I don't have dns.conf in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d. conf.d directory is empty

Comment: Hi, so the RHEL 8 node is a worker node and had exactly same installation process as other nodes. Can you share how you installed the nodes? Please specify which cluster deployment tools you used.

Comment: Yes, RHEL8 is a worker node. One of the RHEL7 server is a master node. Also I added steps I followed to initialize my cluster and applied flannel CNI.

Comment: Can I patch an entire namespace? Also can I restrict that. I know that using `--selector` fails locally. But maybe there is something else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) documentation the list of supported host operating systems is as follows:

> - Ubuntu 16.04+
> - Debian 9+
> - CentOS 7
> - Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7
> - Fedora 25+
> - HypriotOS v1.0.1+
> - Flatcar Container Linux (tested with 2512.3.0)

This [article](https://medium.com/@liau.weijie/how-to-install-docker-and-kubernetes-cluster-on-redhat-8-centos-8-f774fc071e82) mentioned that there are network issues on RHEL 8:

> **(2020/02/11 Update**: After installation, I keep facing pod network issue which is like deployed pod is unable to reach external network
> or pods deployed in different workers are unable to ping each other
> even I can see all nodes (master, worker1 and worker2) are ready via
> *kubectl get nodes*. After checking through the Kubernetes.io official website, I observed the nfstables backend is not compatible with the
> current kubeadm packages. Please refer the following link in “**Ensure
> iptables tooling does not use the nfstables backend**”.

The simplest solution here is to reinstall the node on supported operating system.

Comment: Looking at both articles and other posts, looks like I will have to lower my ambitions to settle down with RHEL7 for now as a worker node. Thanks for pin point to those two pages for reference.